# SOAHC, edit popular questions with (maybe) low quality

Tags: discussion, cleanup

Recently some of the Area51 sites have gotten [CHAOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character).

> ...they will spend a couple of days sweeping up a little bit just to get the place in order. This is the world's most superficial cleanup: they're just looking at the top 1000 questions in order by page views and, if necessary, editing the titles to make them more grammatical, fix spelling, and make them reflect the gist of the question better.

I think this is a great idea by the StackExchange team! While CHAOS is more than just editing and fixing posts - I feel we can go a little further with this idea on our site I think the community as whole here could really benefit from cleaning up a lot of our older posts that may have slipped below the high standards of questions and answers we've come to expect.

I've created a few queries using the StackExchange Data explorer, I'd like to get users of the community the information they need to help our most viewed questions and turn them into stellar examples of Q&A.

- [Top 1000 Questions sorted by Views](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/s/1684/top-1000-viewed-questions)
- [Possible Duplicates: Posts with "Duplicate" in the comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/s/1449/possible-duplicates)
- [Questions with high view counts that have no images](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/s/1608/high-view-counts-with-no-images)

I think it'd be great if we could go through a few a day, making edits *only when necessary* and when it help to improve the content of the question/answer. What are your thoughts?

Comment: note that you can use [advanced search operators](http://askubuntu.com/search) to achieve some of these queries live on your actual site, which is even better than the mildly stale data.se data.. see my answer

Comment: Your Duplicate query includes stuff that's already closed, perhaps it should only list things that are still open.

Answer (score 7):

It's definitely a good idea to tend to your garden, and **particularly those posts which have reached a reasonable view threshold**, meaning they *are* getting found by others on the internet, and *will* represent what your site is to newcomers!

So even if it's your [top 100](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=views%3A4500) or [top 250](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=views%3A2500) questions by views, great idea to start looking at them and making them more awesome:

- edit the title to be clearer
- clean up the tags
- improve the body through editing
- add a relevant screenshot or picture that helps make the question/answer clearer
- improve the answers through editing
- add an awesome answer of your own

Answer (score 6):

Count. Me. In.

However, we'll need to kinda keep tabs on how well this goes. Perhaps use the [Ubuntu Regulators Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators) for communication? Just a thought.